# Bootstrap4 header stuck in mobile display

Tags: navbar, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create the header in the bootstrap 4 (beta) navbar component.
the navbar is stuck in mobile with the hamburgers to show the menu under a dropdowns... but I am on a desktop, so i want it to show as a normal nav bar at top of the page

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/

Here is a simple project with the code for the header only and with the same probleme

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.5/umd/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Browser with the index.html that show my navbar

[image: Broswer with the index.html]

anybody know what is the problem ?

i've tested on a VM and on a Desktop and both do have the same problem...
My Screen Resolution is 1920x1080
The NavBar width is 1920

i'm a bit lost...

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have solved your problem, in the console the navbar is being rendered in "flexbox-direction: column" I have moved the code around added an inline style which should be fairly easy to move to a CSS if you wish. More css work is required after if you want the exact example.

Added the style  `style="flex-direction: row"`

Hope this helps.

```
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto list-inline" style="flex-direction: row">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </ul>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">


                </div>
            </nav>
```

Comment: the problem were from the bootstrap website... their new style doesnt fit with the old one... so when i switched to their new website and using their new tag and class it was working as expected